# Can using incremental (but unique) IDs as a partition key create hot partitions in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html), I understand that DynamoDB will take the value of the provided partition key and put it through a hashing function to decide which physical location the data should go to.

Does this mean writing items with a partition key that is sequential but still unique will produce a hot partition key?

For example, will inserting items with partition key values 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004 allow for even distribution of data across the partitions?

Or will randomly generating a partition key value, like a UUID, make it more evenly distributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB supports two different kinds of primary keys:

1. Partition Key
2. Partition Key + Sort Key

---

### Partition Key

**If you have a primary key with only a partition key, you will rarely encounter a hot partition problem as [in a table that has only a partition key, no two items can have the same partition key value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).**

Your keys are always unique, DynamoDB's internal hash function will always output unique hashes & all of your data will then always be distributed evenly across the logical and physical partitions.

For example, this is the MD5 hash for 10001: `d89f3a35931c386956c1a402a8e09941`

This is the MD5 hash for 10002: `9103c8c82514f39d8360c7430c4ee557`

Even though 10001 has only been incremented by 1, the entire hash is different and is in no way similar to the MD5 hash for 10002.

From a consistent hashing point of view, there is no difference between UUID values or incremental values.

You will only get a hot partition if you're very frequently accessing one specific partition (synonymous with item here) in which case RCUs & WCUs need to be set correctly and you should think of perhaps implementing a caching layer for frequently accessed items.

---

### Partition Key + Sort Key

**If you have a primary key that also contains a sort key, you can have hot partition problems if you're not careful as now you can have duplicate partition key values.**

[All items with the same partition key value are physically stored together, in sorted order by sort key value.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html#HowItWorks.Partitions.CompositeKey)

If you do not have as distinctly as possible primary keys, you can create hot partitions.

Let me give you an example:

An eCommerce website decides to design their orders table like so, with the current date being the partition key and the sort key being the item ID:

```
+---------------+----------+
| Partition Key | Sort Key |
+---------------+----------+
| 19/10/2021    | item3000 |
| 19/10/2021    | item3001 |
| 20/10/2021    | item4000 |
+---------------+----------+
```

That may be working perfectly fine at this scale - in the above example, they process 1000 items a day & this is working fine.

Black Friday - *26/11/2021* - arrives & they now have more than 20000 orders on one day:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Partition Key | Sort Key  |
+---------------+-----------+
| 26/10/2021    | item6000  |
| 26/10/2021    | item15000 |
| 26/10/2021    | item27000 |
| 27/10/2021    | item27100 |
+---------------+-----------+
```

This will create a massive hot partition problem as **all** of the 20000+ orders on 26/10/2021 are now written to **only one** single partition key value (as I mentioned, items with the same partition key will be stored together).

The *26/11/2021* partition key will be **heavily requested & hot, slowing database performance** as you will be trying to process orders and ultimately, you will lose out on revenue due to slow application performance.

The table should be designed in a way to allow for more distinct primary key values in relation to the total primary key count (total items) - write sharding ([random](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html#bp-partition-key-sharding-random) or [calculated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html#bp-partition-key-sharding-calculated)) would prevent this issue if dates must be used as a partition key.

---

**If you do not have a sort key as part of your primary key, do not worry about hot partitions in the sense that is meant in the documentation** - if you have 1/2 frequently accessed items, consider a caching solution perhaps like [DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/).

**If you do have a sort key as part of your primary key, design your table schema in a way that the combination of your partition + sort key is as unique and distinctive as possible to avoid hot partitions.**

Comment: ah, incredible and detailed explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @user1542422 more than welcome, hope that clears it up :)

Comment: You said "If you have a primary key with only a partition key, you will never encounter a hot partition problem" I do not believe this is accurate.  A partition is considered "hot" if it is frequently accessed relative to other partitions. This imbalance in workload is what causes a hot partition, not the absence of a sort key.  Hot partitions happen as a result of an imbalanced workload, not whether or not your primary key is simple vs compound

Comment: I'll rephrase @SethGeoghegan but hot partitions in the way that the documentation states is not to be worried about when using partition keys - I've clarified.

Comment: Can you link where the documentation says this?  It's my understanding that hot partitions arise from uneven data access.  As an extreme example, imagine you have a table with items that have primary keys consisting of only a partition key.  You then write an application that accesses one of these items millions of times per day, but the other items are only accessed 1-2 times/day. This imbalanced access causes a hot partition on the frequently accessed partition. I believe that avoiding hot partitions is about designing your keys to evenly distribute the workload to your table. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Correct and I've reworded to highlight that - if you're accessing a few items a million times per day, you have a bigger fundamental problem of data access and RCU provisioning. My point is that the typical fix for hot partitioning arises from using more distinct values for your primary keys when using partition+sort. I can't really say "access x item less" - your solution is caching using DAX or Redis for example, calling the database less etc. OP looked to be more curious about UUID vs incremental so I class that as out of scope for the answer to this question.